# React: Component vs Hook. Is it really the same?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I translate component to hook code and I have difference between both.
(note that the Refresher is callback the fetchApi to refresh data)

```
export default class myComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { test: false };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchApi();
    }

    fetchApi = () => {
        console.log("fetchApi: " + this.state.test);

        this.setState({ test: !this.state.test }, () => console.log("useEffect: " + this.state.test));
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <label>{"test: " + this.state.test}</label>
            <Refresher refresh={this.fetchApi.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

On my screen, test is switching true to false and false to true at each refresh.

```
export default function myHook(props) {
    const [test, setTest] = useState(false);

    let TEST = false;

    useEffect(() => fetchApi(), []);
    useEffect(() => console.log("useEffect: " + test), [test]);

    const fetchApi = () => {
        console.log("fetchApi: test = " + test);
        console.log("fetchApi: TEST = " + TEST);

        setTest(!test);
        TEST = !TEST;
    }

    return <div>
        <label>{"test: " + test}</label>
        <Refresher refresh={fetchApi} />
    </div>
}
```

On my screen, test is staying on true value

On console.

Component:

```
fetchApi: false
useEffect: true
fetchApi: true
useEffect: false
fetchApi: false
useEffect: true
```

Hook:

```
fetchApi: test = false
fetchApi: TEST = false
useEffect: false
useEffect: true
fetchApi: test = false
fetchApi: TEST = true
fetchApi: test = false
fetchApi: TEST = false
```

Why my test variable is it always to false value?

**EDIT:**
@Andrey Smolko: My console is right but with the button, you are right too. I add my refresher here:

```
export default function Refresher(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    let time = 0;
    let timer = 1;

    useEffect(
        () => {
            timer = props.refreshTimer ?? 5;

            let currentTime = timer > 0 && setInterval(secondEllapsed, 1000);

            return () => clearInterval(currentTime)
        },
        []);

    const secondEllapsed = () => {
        setValue(++time / timer);

        if (time % timer)
            return;

        props.refresh();
    }

    return <>value</>;
}
```

@Victor L.: Your solution seems running well. Is it the same things that @Slbox explained with the dependancy or @Konrad with stale reference.

@Slbox: Is is same for code given by @Victor L.?

@Konrad: Good idea, it means join to the @Victor L. solution

Comment: I think you should be passing `test` as a dependency to the `useEffect` that calls `setTest`.

Comment: Also, it seems that `Refresher` uses a stale reference to `fetchApi`

Comment: Add `props.refresh` to the dependency array of`useEffect` in `Refresher`. You are calling old version of `secondEllapsed` every time

Comment: My solution is similar to the solutions that Slbox and Konrad provided, but it uses a different approach. They explained how to fix it using dependencies or refs. I explained how to fix it using a functional update for setTest, which will use the latest state value. These are different ways to solve the same problem, and they may have different pros and cons depending on the context. For example, using dependencies may cause unnecessary re-rendering or side effects, using refs may cause confusion or inconsistency, and using functional updates may cause complexity or performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

The class components and function components with hooks are not exactly the same, but they are equivalent in most cases.

Your `test` variable is always `false` in the hook code because you are using the stale state value in the `fetchApi` function. When you call `setTest`, you are not updating the `test` variable immediately, but scheduling a state update for the next render. However, the `fetchApi` function still has a closure over the old test value - false.

To fix this, you can use a functional update for `setTest`, which will use the latest state value.

For example:

```
const fetchApi = () => {
  console.log("fetchApi: test = " + test);

  setTest((prevTest) => {
    const newTest = !prevTest;
    console.log("fetchApi: newTest = " + newTest);
    return newTest;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some mistake in logging.
Inside functional component you have a variable:

```
let TEST = false;
```

That variable will be created each render with value false and inside fetchApi (which is also recreated each render) variable TEST always will be false. The TEST variable update to true will not be kept as new variable is created each render. But you have following logging:

```
fetchApi: test = false
fetchApi: TEST = true
fetchApi: test = false
fetchApi: TEST = false
```

where variable TEST has different values. Imho in logging there is a mistake (typo or whatever) and test should true/false and TEST should be always false.

Codesandbox snippet of your example - https://codesandbox.io/s/test-example-lv2qks
And it seems all work as expected.